# Missing File In Bash - Create a file and assign it to a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to create a file and assign it to a variable with these lines:

```
aws_key="company-lab"
source_dir="source_files"
aws_role_list=$(aws iam list-roles --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Roles[].RoleName' > "$source_dir"/aws-"$aws_key"-role-list.txt)
```

But when I go to use the variable "$aws_role_list" it's empty:

```
echo "echo the file"
echo "$aws_role_list"
```

Running the script with bash -x gives you:

```
+ aws_role_list=
```

And listing the file like this:

```
echo "listing the file"
ls -lh "$aws_role_list"
```

Gives you:

```
+ ls -lh ''
ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the aws_role_list variable correctly?

Comment: The question is not how to use aws_role_list variable correctly.  It is what is causing the variable to not have any value.  Decompose the command and see where things fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with AWS, but I can see that you are redirecting a command's output to a file:

```
aws iam list-roles --profile="$aws_key" | 
    jq -r '.Roles[].RoleName' > "$source_dir"/aws-"$aws_key"-role-list.txt
```

Since the output is going into a file, when you use `var=$(command)`, it is reasonable that `var` will be empty because `command` doesn't return anything: it's all going to `"$source_dir"/aws-"$aws_key"-role-list.txt`.

So, you either want this:

```
aws_role_list=$(aws iam list-roles --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Roles[].RoleName')
```

Or this:

```
aws iam list-roles --profile="$aws_key" | 
    jq -r '.Roles[].RoleName' > "$source_dir"/aws-"$aws_key"-role-list.txt
aws_role_list=$(cat "$source_dir"/aws-"$aws_key"-role-list.txt)
```

If you are trying to get the file's name and not its contents into the variable, then you want this:

```
aws_key="company-lab"
source_dir="source_files"
aws_role_list="$source_dir"/aws-"$aws_key"-role-list.txt
aws iam list-roles --profile="$aws_key" | 
    jq -r '.Roles[].RoleName' > "$aws_role_list"
```